# No more pulldown menus and popup windows in many apps on (smaller) primary screen

Tags: display, applications

I run a Schenker VIA 14 laptop with eOS 517 Hera (recent fresh install) and for several apps (Clementine, qps, my-weather-indicator and others) which I usually have on the built-in (primary) laptop screen (FullHD) rather than on my 4k secondary screen I do not see any pull-downs. Once I move them to the large secondary screen, I first have a vertically maximized pull-down and if I active the pull-down a second time it reacts normal. Once I move the app back to the smaller primary screen the pull-downs are gone again (modal locking in effect). Other apps like Firefox and Thunderbird behave as expected on both screen.

Comment: Now also file dialog popup windows for Thunderbird become "invisble" when I initiate them from the smaller main window. ESC usually end this popup problem by closing the popup. When I move thunderbird to the bigger (4k) secondary window and repeat the same I see the popup. When I define the bigger window a main window this does not happen anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately I use the 4k monitor for my other (work) laptop while I use the small built-in monitor to have an eye on the always-on things an my personal eOS laptop. That's why I have the smaller screen set as main to force opening of new windows without needing to switch the 4k screen every time. Use to work perfectly up to a few days ago - now its getting anoying.